# Why react-router fires push and pop action when replacing path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I've a react app. In a component I have a Link comp from the react-router.
When I click on the link the router fires a push and a pop action?
Is it normal? This way I don't know how can I solve a problem.
I have a route setup like this: example/:param
and when I'm on this path how can I listen properly for the param segments change?

Code:

```
class Example extends Component {
    fetch(param) {
        // ajax stuff
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetch(this.props.param);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.fetch(nextProps.param);
    }

    render() {
        // render stuff
    }
}

const stateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        param: ownProps.params.param,
    };
};

export default connect(stateToProps, {})(Profile);
```

This way componentWillReceiveProps runs twice beacuse router fires push and the pop action.

Thx for any help/advice,
Akos

Comment: react-router doesnot dispatch any action. Are you using react-router-redux?